# Document type does not allow element "link" here

Tags: hyperlink

First i got the error while validating my code in Sortsite as "Document type does not allow element "Style" here." So i removed style portion and kept in a new css sheet.
After that while validating, i got "Document type does not allow element "link" here." error.
here is the code:

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="d" uri="/dror-tags" %>

<link href="<s:url value='/styles/menu.css' includeParams="none"/>" 
              rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/> 
<!-- Action URLs -->
<s:url id="dppUrl" namespace="/xyz" action="abc" includeParams="none"/>
<s:url id="dppUrl" namespace="/xyz" action="abc" includeParams="none"/>

<d:button value="Menu" submenuId="mainSubmenu" cssStyle="float: left;"/>
<div dojoType="dror:PopupMenu2" widgetId="mainSubmenu" submenuOverlap="0">
    <div dojoType="dror:MenuItem2" 
         caption="xyz" 
         onclick="try { window.location = '${xyzUrl}'; } catch (e) { };">
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only valid location for that `<link>` tag in a HTML document is between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags. You're getting that error because that's not the case in your code.

From the [HTML spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#the-link-element):

> If the rel attribute is used, the element is restricted to the head element.

Comment: So where i need to add head tags?

Comment: So where i need to add head tags?   <%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="d" uri="/dror-tags" %>
<head>
<link href="<s:url value='/styles/menu.css' includeParams="none"/>" 
              rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/> 
</head>  Is it correct now???

Comment: @Sandhya I think you need to go back to basics and read about the structure of HTML documents. The very basic structure is: `<html><head>...</head><body>...</body></html>`